# Выпадающие списки в блоке категорий

Tags: javascript

Вот готовый код для решения задачи. Проблема в том, что слайдинга и изменений никаких не происходит. Я уже пытался проверять версии плагина jcarousellite_1.0.1.js. Может быть в этом проблема) Вроде бы всё со стилями в порядке, с выводом на index-ый файл. А вот проблема не уходит. Есть ещё полный вид документа, однако там другая функция, которая не относится к теме. В структуре документа и с форматированием тоже вроде бы всё в порядке. Идентификаторы блокам ul, я тоже указал, смещение или плавное раскрытие списка не происходит.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#block-category > ul > li > a').click(function(){

    if ($($this).attr('class') != 'active') {

        $('#block-category > ul > li > ul').slideUp(400);
        $(this).next().slideToggle(400);

        $('#block-category > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $.cookie('select_cat', $(this).attr('id'));
    } else {
        $('#block-category > ul > li > a').removeClass('active'); 
        $('#block-category > ul > li > ul').slideUp(400);
        $.cookie('select_cat', '');
    }

  });

  if ($cookie('select_cat') != '') {
    $('#block-category > ul > li > #'+$.cookie('select_cat')).addClass('active').next().show();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это что за способ проверки класса у элемента:

```
if ($($this).attr('class') != 'active') {
```

и откуда взялась переменная `$this`?

Надо

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, не могу только понять почему там has class. Может быть и так тоже можно записать, я просто поменял, убрал знак доллара в скобках и заработало.

Comment: @Александр если у этого элемента в атрибуте класс будут перечислены несколько классов, проверка даст неверный результат, даже если среди них и будет `active`

Comment: А я понял, я не увидел! перед переменной, просто уже привык к такой записи, наверно изменить код, а то такие ошибки убивают иногда)))

Comment: @Александр Очень хорошо. Не забывайте принимать ответы на Ваши вопросы - знак "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: то есть выполнение кода остановиться, если active не на первом месте или вся проблема в принципи в записи. Он не станет проверять все классы, а просто выдаст не правильный результат?

Comment: @Александр Да, второе - "неправильный результат".

Comment: Похоже прийдётся вернуться к азам, а то трачу время на такие мелочи довольно не малое,  вернёмся к литературе. Нужно просто навык наработать. Спасибо за ответ.